# How to draw barplot on either side of the y-axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, bar-chart, reshape

I am trying to draw a `barplot` on either side of the `y-axis` (atleast present in "YES" or "NO") instead of stacking both "YES" and "NO" together. Firstly I convert the `data.frame` to longer format > Calculated `mean` > ggplot2.

When I ran the ggplot2 code, the `barplot` is stacked with both "YES" and "NO" together (see screenshot below). I have provided example data that I am using to plot. Basically, I would like to view as expected plot. Is there any additional step that I am missing? Please assist.

```
dput(Data)
structure(list(SampleID = c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", 
                            "Sample_4", "Sample_5", "Sample_6"), Sustained_CR = c("NO", "NO", 
                                                                                  "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES"), Gene_A = c(2.245937679, 0, 0, 1.128343065, 
                                                                                                                         0, 0), Gene_CCC = c(83.09969414, 16.10799215, 122.2752332, 57.54549633, 
                                                                                                                                             13.12780895, 62.70159708), Gene_XED = c(6.737813038, 1.006749509, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     12.80978634, 1.128343065, 0, 2.508063883), RNA = c(580.5748901, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        312.0923478, 347.0287571, 292.2408539, 355.7636226, 125.4031942
                                                                                                                                                                                     )), row.names = c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", "Sample_3", "Sample_4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Sample_5", "Sample_6"), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
Data_long <- Data[, -c(1)] %>% pivot_longer(cols = -"Sustained_CR",names_to="Gene_Symbols",values_to="Normalized expression values")
sum(is.na(Data_long))
head(Data_long)

## Calculate the mean based on the Gene_Symbols
Data_mean <- Data_long %>% group_by(Gene_Symbols, Sustained_CR) %>% summarize(Norm_exp=mean(`Normalized expression values`, na.rm = T))
print(Data_mean)
Gene_Symbols Sustained_CR Norm_exp
<chr>        <chr>           <dbl>
  1 Gene_A       NO              0.749
2 Gene_A       YES             0.376
3 Gene_CCC     NO             73.8  
4 Gene_CCC     YES            44.5  
5 Gene_XED     NO              6.85 
6 Gene_XED     YES             1.21 
7 RNA          NO            413.   
8 RNA          YES           258.   


ggplot(Data_mean, aes(reorder(Gene_Symbols, -Norm_exp), Norm_exp, fill = Sustained_CR)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Gene_Symbols")
```

[image]

Actually, I dont want the stacked barplot on either side. The bar should be either present in "YES" or "NO" only.
[image]

Thank You,

Toufiq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `Norm_exp` values negative when `Sustained_CR` is "NO":

```r
Data_mean %>% 
  mutate(Norm_exp = ifelse(Sustained_CR == "YES", Norm_exp, -Norm_exp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Gene_Symbols, -Norm_exp), Norm_exp, fill = Sustained_CR)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Gene_Symbols") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = abs)
```

[image]

Comment: If I am correct, the OP doesn't want the barplot to be stacked right?

Comment: @Allan Cameron thank you. Actually, I dont want the stacked barplot on either side. The bar should be either present in "YES" or "NO" only.

Comment: @Quinten yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @MOHAMMEDTOUFIQ see my update - is that what you mean?

Comment: @AllanCameron Excellent. Thank you so much. One question, why is necessary to make the Norm_exp values negative when Sustained_CR is "NO":

Comment: @MOHAMMEDTOUFIQ this is what makes the bars point to the left (negative values go left, positive go right)

Comment: As always perfect! +1

Comment: @AllanCameron OK. If I want the other way, I can simply remove `negative` sign.